# How to add a column in a CSV file while converting Image folder to CSV file in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, mnist

I have lots of Images of digits in a folder which I have converted in a CSV file, but like in MNIST data set when we converted a digit in a CSV file it has a label column attached to it but when I converted my image folder into CSV , my CSV file does not consist of Label column.

Please help me how can I add a label column  in my own created CSV file.
Code I have written is below:-

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import csv  

# default format can be changed as needed
def createFileList(myDir, format='.jpg'):
    fileList = []
    print(myDir)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myDir, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(format):
                fullName = os.path.join(root, name)
                fileList.append(fullName)
    return fileList

# load the original image
myFileList = createFileList('/path_to_directory_with_images/')

for file in myFileList:
    print(file)
    img_file = Image.open(file)
    # img_file.show()

    # get original image parameters...
    width, height = img_file.size
    format = img_file.format
    mode = img_file.mode

    # Make image Greyscale
    img_grey = img_file.convert('L')
    #img_grey.save('result.png')
    #img_grey.show()

    # Save Greyscale values
    value = np.asarray(img_grey.getdata(), dtype=np.int).reshape((img_grey.size[1], img_grey.size[0]))
    value = value.flatten()
    print(value)
    with open("name_you_want.csv", 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are having sub-directories inside a directory where each sub-directory denotes a class.

I have also faced a similar albeit not exact issue in the past, here's how I handled it.

1. Make a dictionary object with your class name as keys and their ordinal encoded value as the value of the key.

Code-Ex:-

```
class_label = {

  'angry' : '0', 
  'disgust' : '1', 
  'fear' : '2', 
  'happy' : '3', 
  'neutral' : '4', 
  'sad' : '5',
  'surprise' : '6'

}
```

Here, in the above example, my classes are the keys and their ordinal value as defined by me is the key's value.

2. Loop on your directory folder containing the sub-directories harnessing the key name of the dictionary defined above.

Code-Ex:-

```
image_label = []
file_name = []
for label in class_label:
    files = glob.glob( directory_path + label + '/*.jpg' )
    for names in files:
        file_name.append( names )
        image_label.append( str( class_label[label] ) )
```

This way you will have your full file-name in `file_name` and their corresponding label in `image_label`

Note- The above function is just for the sack of answer, you may want to change it to suit your objective.

3. return `image_label` and `file_name` both from your `createFileList(..)` function( Assuming you changed the `createFileList(..)` function as per the above code )
4. 

Code-Ex:-

```
img_label, file_name = createFileList( .. )

for i in range( len( file_name ) ):
    .
    .
    .
    value = np.asarray(...)
    value = value.flatten()
    value.append( img_label[i] )
    print(value)
    with open("name_you_want.csv", 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(value)
```

Dhanyawad.